# is $g(\lambda) = (\{x\epsilon R^d :f(x) = \lambda\})$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Im struggling to understand why g is measurable and what the integral of g is in the following theorem:

Let $ f: R^d -> R$ be measurable and define $g:R->[0,\infty]$ by $g(\lambda) = (\{x\epsilon R^d :f(x) = \lambda\})$. Then g is measurable. How do we determine $\int _R g(\lambda)d\lambda$ ?

I know that to show a function is measurable, then we need to show that any set $[0,a]$ gets mapped to sets in R by $g^{-1}$ that get mapped to measurable sets in $R^d$ by $f^{-1}$. But Im having trouble proving this and what the integral of g is on R.

Comment: $g(\lambda)$ is the *measure* of $\{x \in \mathbb R^d : f(x) = \lambda\}$, right?

Comment: Or is it the cardinality of that?  The $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure might be $0$ for all $\lambda$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг yes, the lebesgue measure.

Comment: Then $g$ is measurable but the integral need not be infinite. For example, consider $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_d) = x_1$, the first projection. The set $\{f(x) = \lambda\}$ is the $d-1$ dimensional hyperplane $x_1 = \lambda$, which has Lebesgue measure zero. Hence, $g(\lambda) = 0$ for all $\lambda$, so the integral over $\mathbb R$ is also zero, a contradiction to your statement.

Comment: The essential reason why this does not work, is that the sum of an uncountable number of zeros (as in : the sum of Lebesgue measure of uncountably many disjoint planes) is zero, but the union ends up covering the whole space, so "uncountable additivity" is coming into play.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Then I think I wrote the theorem wrong. I remember the integral of g on R should be well defined, can we calculate it?

Comment: I'm feeling sleepy now, so I will get back to you on the morrow. But I will look for a workable version

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that $\mu$ is a measure in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and for all Borel set $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ define $\nu(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A))$. It can be proved that $\nu$ is a measure in $\mathbb{R}$.
Thus we have $g(t)=\nu(\{t\})=f_*\mu(\{t\})$ is measurable and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f|$

In fact, in general, we have that if $dF_{*}\mu$ denote the image measure than:
$$\int_X \phi (F(x)) d\mu=\int_Y \phi(y) dF_*\mu$$

Comment: How did you get $\int_{\mathbb{R}} g = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f|$ ?

Comment: I understand the first part, what does the lower star notation here mean? Is it composition? $g(t)=\nu(\{t\})=f_*\mu(\{t\})$